# Help with a recursive limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am studying for my finals and one of my professors posted a problem on the practice finals, but I am stuck and have no idea what to do. The question is to prove that

$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=1$ where $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{x_n^2+1}$ and $x_0=2$.

I tried using the MCT with little success, as this function oscillates below and above 1, so I can't say that its bounded above or below by 1. Can anyone give me any tips on how to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Consider the subsequences $x_0, x_2, x_4, \dotsc$ and $x_1, x_3, x_5, \dotsc$

Comment: Sometimes considering $y_n=x_n-1$ can help in problems like this.